# Modal Alternatives?

Tags: html, css, popup, modal-dialog

I am in the process of building a site with a large amoutn of divs, perhaps 300-1,000.  Each are small, 100x100, and when the user clicks on each div a small modal pops up w/ basic info about each div, maybe 2-3 paragraphs and some images; all this works great.  However, I fear as the divs increase in quantity, this amount of images/texts that are loaded will slow down the site to a crawl, resulting in a terrible ux; it's also aesthetically dispeasing to me (and I'm sure to other coders) to have so much code on a single page.  So the question is thus: what is the best way to make modals that load quickly, but don't slow down the site, or are there alternatives to them?

1. I thought about imbedding the modal content (text,images) inside CSS, and perhaps makig it between 2-5 css files?
2. I thought about pop-ups, but those are problematic, as some browsers won't respond to the specific size dimensions of a pop-up, (IE), and some block pop-ups all together.

Has anyone else dealt w/ this or has an interesting solution?

I appreciate everyones help.

Comment: Use server-side code to populate the modal content once a user clicks on it. This will reduce your load by a significant amount if you have that many different modals.

Comment: I think the best way make one modal that will be loading info from data-params of div. Also you can load your div and modal info by ajax request when user scroling down (like in social networks). But for this you'll to use server side code.

Comment: If you interested only on html implemention, you can devide pages on little pages and load it by ajax and append it to all divs container